# is there webview on ios that renders like Chrome?

Tags: ios, webview

I want to show a website in a WebView, but it doesn't work on safari (desktop or mobile) and my android version works but not the ios. Is there any way to make WebView render like chrome or some alternative to default WebView?

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://website.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: edited to add code

Comment: there is only one web engine allowed on iOS: __Safari's engine__; therefore it is better to optimise your website for that rather than finding an option which does not even exist.